# Can someone tell me why DIRECTOR doesn't like this lua file?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [director: (params) error on 'menu'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807401/director-params-error-on-menu)

This works in the simulator and not on the actual device. Returns a Director ERROR params could not load 'menu'. I have a mix of director class using screens but in the simulator not returns on errors. Its just when I install the app and after I use the intro screen.

```
module(..., package.seeall)
new = function ( params )


local localGroup = display.newGroup()


        ------------------
        -- Imports
        ------------------

        local ui = require ( "ui" )

        ------------------
        -- Groups
        ------------------


        ------------------
        -- Display Objects
        ------------------

        local background = display.newImage( "Cand.png" )
        local title      = display.newText( "Director Class", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 16 )
        local createdBy  = display.newText( "Created by Stephen", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 16 )
        local website    = display.newText( "http://www.joinm.com", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 16 )

        ------------------
        -- Link
        ------------------

        local goBlog = function ( event )
                if event.phase == "ended" then
                        system.openURL( "http://www.joinm.com" )
                end
        end
        --

        createdBy:addEventListener( "touch", goBlog )
        website:addEventListener( "touch", goBlog )

        --====================================================================--
        -- BUTTONS
        --====================================================================--

        ------------------
        -- Functions
        ------------------

        local bt01 = function ( event )
                if event.phase == "release" then
                        director:changeScene( "stb01", "moveFromRight" )                        
                end
        end
        --
        local bt02 = function ( event )
                if event.phase == "release" then
                        director:changeScene( "word", "overFromRight" )
                end
        end
        --
        local bt03 = function ( event )
                if event.phase == "release" then
                        director:changeScene( "Hol", "moveFromTop" )
                end
        end
        --
        local bt04 = function ( event )
                if event.phase == "release" then
                        director:changeScene( "cat", "overFromBottom" )
                end
        end
        --
        local bt05 = function ( event )
                if event.phase == "release" then
                        director:changeScene( "Ion", "flip" )
                end
        end
        --
        local bt06 = function ( event )
                if event.phase == "release" then
                        director:changeScene( "ni", "downFlip" )
                end
        end

        ------------------
        -- UI Objects
        ------------------

        local bt01 = ui.newButton{
                                        default = "Bi.png",
                                        over = "Bi.png",
                                        onEvent = bt01,
                                        id = "bt01"
        }
        --
        local bt02 = ui.newButton{
                                        default = "eu.png",
                                        over = "eu.png",
                                        onEvent = bt02,
                                        id = "bt02"
        }
        --
        local bt03 = ui.newButton{
                                        default = "do.png",
                                        over = "do.png",
                                        onEvent = bt03,
                                        id = "bt03"
        }
        --
        local bt04 = ui.newButton{
                                        default = "hp.png",
                                        over = "hp.png",
                                        onEvent = bt04,
                                        id = "bt04"
        }
        --
        local bt05 = ui.newButton{
                                        default = "ca.png",
                                        over = "ca.png",
                                        onEvent = bt05,
                                        id = "bt05"
        }
        --
        local bt06 = ui.newButton{
                                        default = "Ca.png",
                                        over = "Ca.png",
                                        onEvent = bt06,
                                        id = "bt06"
        }





                ------------------
                -- Inserts
                ------------------

                localGroup:insert( background )
                localGroup:insert( title )
                localGroup:insert( createdBy )
                localGroup:insert( website )
                localGroup:insert( bt01 )
                localGroup:insert( bt02 )
                localGroup:insert( bt03 )
                localGroup:insert( bt04 )
                localGroup:insert( bt05 )
                localGroup:insert( bt06 )

                ------------------
                -- Positions
                ------------------


                bt01.x = 105
                bt01.y = 580
                --
                bt02.x = 270
                bt02.y = 580
                --
                bt03.x = 435
                bt03.y = 580
                --
                bt04.x = 610
                bt04.y = 580
                --
                bt05.x = 785
                bt05.y = 580
                --
                bt06.x = 920
                bt06.y = 580
                --

                createdBy.x = 160
                createdBy.y = 440
                --
                website.x = 160
                website.y = 460


                ------------------
                -- Colors
                ------------------


                ------------------
                -- Listeners
                ------------------


        ------------------
        -- Listener
        ------------------




        ------------------
        -- Initiate variables
        ------------------



        ------------------
        -- MUST return a display.newGroup()
        ------------------

        return localGroup;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the file names of your images.  They are case sensitive, though the Windows simulator doesn't show any error.

For instance, since you use `display.newImage( "Cand.png" )` your image file must be "Cand.png" and not "cand.png"